# Flask app publicly available, but not available to PHP cURL

Tags: python, php, flask, curl, networking

I have hosted a Flask app on an EC2 instance, and successfully spun it up. I can query it using cURL from the command line of my machine, from Python, from Postman, and from its own local terminal. The app is visible to the public. I have set custom inbound TCP rules on the EC2 instance to allow traffic from all IPs. However, when I execute cURL commands in PHP to get API responses onto a website, I get the error "Failed to connect to [my server + my port] after 1000 ms: Couldn't connect to server". The timeout is always after 1000ms.

This is the Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import numpy as np
from urllib.parse import unquote
import pandas as pd
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

# internal functions

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST','GET'])
@cross_origin()
def search():
    search_text = request.json['search_text']
    # do stuff to make response object
    response = jsonify({'data': response})
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000,debug=True)
```

And this is the PHP that fails:

```
    $url = #url of EC2 instance

    $data = json_encode([
        "search_text" => "soup"
    ]);
    
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($data)
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
```

I'm befuddled because I am able to access other external sites via PHP on this same server, including with curl_exec(), shell_exec(), and file_get_contents() - so I don't think it's a firewall or general server setting issue. And I'm able to hit the API via several other methods, from public addresses, with no issues. The cURL error "couldn't connect to server" is not too helpful; does anyone have experience with similar issues?

Comment: I would bet it is because of CORS

Comment: Any reason you're setting the headers twice there, and with different values? I think the second one should be removed. Also, does it take longer than 1000ms when running curl from the command line?

Comment: @dawid.pawlowski CORS restrictions only apply to ajax requests made from a browser so no, it won't be that. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to learn how CORS actually works.

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate the replies. As to headers, that's just an oversight / sloppy code on my part as I've been trying any and everything to just get even a basic reply from the server. When I cURL the same endpoint from command line the response is delivered in <50ms, so I don't think it's timing out if that's what you were driving at.